# Software to straighten an oblique rectangle (due to picture perspective) to 2D rectangle

Tags: gratis, linux, image-processing, 3d

I took a picture of a plaque, but it is oblique due to the perspective.

How do I straighten it to a 2D rectangle?

Requirements:

- I would only have to click 4 points, push a button, and that's all.
- Free
- Runs on Linux (Java OK)

Bonus for recognizing the borders and calculating the curve, but it is not really required.

I tried Gimp's "Perspective" transformation tool: it is really hard to get the point right. The result almost never makes a satisfying rectangle, even after many tries. The opposite approach would be so much easier.

Answer (score 2):

[Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) has tools, normally used to correct barrel & perspective errors, to do exactly what you need see the tutorial [here](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/architectural/en.shtml) for an example but here are a couple of screenshots:

- You may have to pick a couple more points
- Free
- Cross Platform including Linux

The process:
 - Run hugin and set advanced interface
 - Load your photo 
 - In feature matching select Vertical Lines & Click Create control points
 - Check you control points and add at least one on a horizontal feature
 - Ensure that on the Photos tab the optimise is set to Custom Parameters then click calculate and yes
 - On the optimize tab click optimize
 - Check the result
 - Stitch to produce the final output.

## Before

[image: Before]

## After a quick play

[image: After]

Not quite there yet but with a better set of control points...

Comment: The result is not a rectangle though... If I understand well, the goal of this tool is to remove the lens distortion, but the resulting image is still in what I call perspective.

Comment: I only had a very short amount of time, (and limited sample set), to produce a sample picture - why not give it a try with your plaque?  Better yet why not attach you picture to the question then I (and others) could possible run with it and you could see the results.

Answer (score 1):

[Perspec](https://github.com/feramhq/perspec) is exactly made for this use case: [github.com/feramhq/perspec](https://github.com/feramhq/perspec).

[image]

[image]

(Disclaimer: I'm the main developer)

Runs on macOS, Linux.

License: GNU Affero General Public License v3.0